# Issue with asp.net validation control with IE?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I do have a strange problem here with asp.net required field validation controls.To my understanding **validator controls render client-side script for IE users so no postback occurs in case there's a problem with data entry.** So when i was running my web app on my local machine which has IE8 its working fine which has windows XP on it.But when i deploy it on IIS  6 in WS2003 it some how bypasses the validators and makes a post back to the server.Does it have some thing to do with the IE or IIS or ASP.net version ????

Comment: Is the target framework different on the other server?

Comment: target framework is 3.5 ...asp.net version 1.1.4322

Answer (score 0):

Go into IIS, and under the ASP.NET tab select the latest ASP.NET version available in the list.